# Syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ')'

Tags: multilingual, php

I've followed the tutorial in [these](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v7vCp_TFcdU) [YT videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vI4NkAERO0E) to build a language switcher and bilingual site in PHP (no framework). When I try to test it in WAMP, however, I get the following error:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ')' in C:\wamp\www\skydoll\lang\francais.php on line 6**

I have found by searching this site that this is often caused by the line above the reported error line, but being new to PHP I can't seem to find anything wrong with the code.

```
<?php

$lang = array(
'hello' => 'Bonjour',
'goodbye' => 'Au revoir'
);

?>
```

Anything looks out of place?

Before I got to this point, however, I got other syntax errors in the file init.php, which is the file calling francais.php. Could the error be coming from there? I'll include the code for that as well in case:

```
<?php 
session_start();

$allowed_lang = array('english', 'francais');

if (isset($_GET['lang']) === true && in_array($_GET['lang'], allowed_lang) === true) {
$_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
} else if (isset($_SESSION['lang']) === false) {
$_SESSION['lang'] = 'francais';
}

include 'lang/' . $_SESSION['lang'] . '.php';
?>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Which line is the 6th in francais.php? The error is more helpful with that.

Comment: There's no syntax error in the code you showed. Make sure you included *C:\wamp\www\skydoll\lang\francais.php* in your question.

Comment: @meze Notice the lack of `$` in `allowed_lang` in line 6.

Comment: @loganfsmyth the 6th line is the one with ); in fact.

Comment: @Gaui it's still valid php code though with a wrong statement

Comment: I'd have to disagree that this question is too localized because it seems like a common php error or at least I have the same problem too.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (isset($_GET['lang']) === true && in_array($_GET['lang'], allowed_lang) === true) {
```

Should be:

```
if (isset($_GET['lang']) === true && in_array($_GET['lang'], $allowed_lang) === true) {
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I still get the same error even with that mistake fixed.

Comment: Are you sure that it's the exactly same error?

Comment: I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ')' in C:\wamp\www\skydoll\lang\francais.php on line 6, so yes.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot place `$` character before `allowed_lang`